# Spot or ban telegram subsciber in a channel who uses bots?

Tags: api, bots, telegram, channel

I have a telegram channel, and some of my subscribers use bots to redirect my messages.

Is there any way to find out who those users are?

Or is there any way to ban bots from my channel?

If anyone has another solution, please inform me.

Answer (score 0):

Bots can not join your channel, only you(as a creator or an authorized admin) can add them as the "admins" of the channel.

If you have spotted automatic forwarding of your channel's messages, they are being done utilizing Telegram's core api which is used by regular telegram accounts. So there is np way to find out that which one of your subscribers is also manipulated by core APIs.